# MySQL - Join by only append a row of aggregated values from source table to each of selected rows on host table

Tags: mysql, join

I have a situation which I can describe in a simple way as below.

> Table A has fields X, Y, and Z.
>
> Table B is a reference table with fields P and Q.
>
> Y targets to P as foreign reference.
>
> X-Y is not set as unique because the paired values is repeatable.
>
> X-Y-Z is generally distinct but Z is only text in type so it is not indexed.

In a `select` query from table A, I only want to append to each row based on their value of Y, the `sum` of all values of Q. But when I do something like below, it shows only one single row for each distinct X-Y value.

```
select X, Z, sum(Q) from A where ___ join B on Y = P group by X, Y
```

Is there any other way I could try before I consider adding an ID field as last option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you perform the aggregation from `B` in a derived table, you can then `JOIN` that to table `A` to get the SUM on every row of `A`:

```
SELECT A.*, B.Q
FROM A
JOIN (SELECT P, SUM(Q) AS Q
      FROM B
      GROUP BY P) B ON B.P = A.Y
```

Comment: thank you. definitely solve my problem. just asking. doing this way are there any drawback in performance?

Comment: @jerinho no worries. This should be the most efficient way of generating this result.